# Where to Find the Translations for the WPToolkit

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am attempting to find where the resx string translations are kept in the WPToolkit. Specifically, I would like to see the OK and Cancel application bar translations. I am creating a custom MessageBox for my application and I want to ensure that the OK and Cancel buttons maintain the exact resx translations that would match the WPToolkit's application bar translations. I know I could use a resx translator or just simply Bing or Google, but a lot of times words like OK and Cancel dont necessarily translate (or are the same) and I have no way of knowing if its correct or there was no match in the translator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPToolkit is an open sourced project, so you can browse it [here](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)

The part you are interested in is located [here](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.Localization/Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.Localization.csproj)

`Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.Localization` project. Look at [LocalizedResources](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.Localization/LocalizedResources/) folder. All `resx` files are hidden there.

Comment: Well, what I'm wondering is where the resx files are saved so that I may open them and see the translated strings.

Comment: Up from the "here" link in the above post, browse to the [LocalizedResources](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.Localization/LocalizedResources/) folder. It's full of the desired resource files.